# How to create this relationship in Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I've got a problem with the following relationship (look at the picture below). I don't know, how to create `ArticleAbout` in [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) :( I've got Product, Brand and Article models created yet. What should I have to do now?

[image: relationship]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the Articles are related to the brands and products (I'm assuming that any one article can refer to multiple products and/or multiple brands).
The best way to accomplish that is to set up a n:m relationship from Article to Products and Brands. The docs explain this in more detail here:
[Sequelize Docs - Association#Scopes](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/associations/#scopes)

so, for example:

```
Article = sequelize.define('article', {
    title: DataTypes.String,
    text: DataTypes.TEXT
});

ArticleAbout = sequelize.define('article_about', {
    about_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        unique: 'about_article_ref'
    },
    about: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: 'about_article_ref',
    },
    reference_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        unique: 'about_article_ref',
        references: null
    }
});

Brand.belongsToMany(Article, {
    through: {
        model: ArticleAbout,
        unique: false.
        scope: {
            about: 'brand'
        }
    },
    foreignKey: 'reference_id',
    constraints: false
});

Product.belongsToMany(Article, {
    through: {
        model: ArticleAbout,
        unique: false.
        scope: {
            about: 'product'
        }
    },
    foreignKey: 'reference_id',
    constraints: false
});

Article.belongsToMany(Brand, {
    through: {
        model: ArticleAbout,
        unique: false
    },
    foreignKey: 'about_id'
});

Article.belongsToMany(Product, {
    through: {
        model: ArticleAbout,
        unique: false
    },
    foreignKey: 'about_id'
});
```

The key pieces being `unique: 'string'`, and the `through:`

By setting unique to a string, you are telling Sequelize to compose that key as part of a composite key, meaning that several objects can be associated to one key. The `constraints: false` instructs the compiler to stop screaming at you for all of the cross-reference foreign keys.

Setting the `through:` sets up the relationships through a table exactly like what you are describing in the AboutArticle table you're using.

Then you can start adding articles to products and brands:

```
product.addArticle(article);
brand.addArticle(article);
```

Which that, querying the table becomes a very simple task:

```
Article.getProducts();
Article.getBrands();
Product.getArticles();
Brand.getArticles();
```

Hope that helps.